# Create table from query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I managed to apply the PIVOT statement you suggested to transpose the values ​​of the records of a table as columns automatically:

```
DECLARE @PivotColumnas VARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT    @PivotColumnas = COALESCE (@PivotColumnas + ',[' + IB_PDSBATCHATTRIBIDBI + ']', '[' + IB_PDSBATCHATTRIBIDBI + ']') FROM PDSBATCHATTRIB

DECLARE @PivotTablaSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SET  @PivotTablaSQL = N' SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT INVENTBATCHID, ITEMID, PDSBATCHATTRIB.IB_PDSBATCHATTRIBIDBI, PDSBATCHATTRIBVALUE FROM PDSBATCHATTRIBUTES
  LEFT JOIN PDSBATCHATTRIB ON PDSBATCHATTRIBUTES.IB_PDSBATCHATTRIBIDBI = PDSBATCHATTRIB.IB_PDSBATCHATTRIBIDBI) AS TablaOrigen
 PIVOT
 (MIN(PDSBATCHATTRIBVALUE)
 FOR IB_PDSBATCHATTRIBIDBI IN ('+ @PivotColumnas + ')) AS PivotTable' 

EXECUTE (@PivotTablaSQL)
```

What I need is how to save the result as a query or create a table from this query. If I try to save the result as a query, I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear where you are getting an error. How are you using the code above? Can you provide more details?

Comment: This code is paste into a new view from SQL Server Management Studio. If I execute the query the result is presented on the Results pane but if I try to save it, shows the message with the previous error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, is very simple in fact!

I only have to add the command `INTO NewTable` in the `SELECT` sentence oof the pivot table, just like that:

```
SET  @PivotTablaSQL = N' SELECT * **INTO NewTable** 
FROM (SELECT INVENTBATCHID, ITEMID, PDSBATCHATTRIB.IB_PDSBATCHATTRIBIDBI,   PDSBATCHATTRIBVALUE FROM PDSBATCHATTRIBUTES 
LEFT JOIN PDSBATCHATTRIB ON PDSBATCHATTRIBUTES.IB_PDSBATCHATTRIBIDBI =  PDSBATCHATTRIB.IB_PDSBATCHATTRIBIDBI) AS TablaOrigen 
PIVOT 
(MIN(PDSBATCHATTRIBVALUE) 
FOR IB_PDSBATCHATTRIBIDBI IN ('+ @PivotColumnas + ')) AS PivotTable'
```

This create a new table in the SQL database with the pivot table results.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a dynamic sql, and you don`t know the exact columns, you can use an SELECT ... INTO #TempPivot. It is creating a temporary table what you can use later, or try to build up a dynamic solution which can select the temp table's structure and create a table, however it seems a bit overkill.